# Does Indigo have manual check-in to get boarding pass?

Tags: air-travel, india, domestic-travel, indigo

I have booked a domestic flight using go.indigo.com . Flight is from Pune to Kochi and back.

Now they are asking to do web check-in in which you have to choose a seat which ranges anywhere from INR 450 to INR 800/- and beyond for a seat one way. I am ok with any seat and do not want to choose a seat as the flight is pretty short.

Is there anywhere out of this ?

I would rather go to the check-in counter or gate counter and get whatever seat is there at last.

Comment: How long still till your flight? I have seen several companies where you seem to can only get a seat when you pay, open up a check in for free on the last 24 hours. (I have not traveled in your part of the world.)

Comment: its supposed to be a short one, as per the flight schedule supposed to be 1.5 hrs. each way.

Comment: When do you plan to travel? Tomorrow?

Comment: yup, though I searched on the web and got very differing answers. The only thing I don't wanna have is getting bumped off at the last minute but let's see . There seems to be lot of occupancy left or to be taken at this point in time.

Comment: Not all indigo seats are charged. Middle seats and those at the end are free. You can scroll to back of plane and choose one of the free seats. Airport checkin is always available and you can get left over seats then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indigo (or for that matter any Indian carrier) offers airport check-in.

<s>Even for web check-in, a lot of seats are available for free - these include the middle seats and those at the back of the plane. You can choose one of them and complete the check-in.</s>

**Update:** As per [revised web check-in policy](https://www.twitter.com/IndiGo6E/status/1066560173202784258) all seat selections now have an associated fee.

If you don't want to pay for the seat and don't mind being seated anywhere, just go to the airlines counter at airport and they will allot a random seat at check-in. If you are lucky you may get a premium seat for free (Window or aisle and in front of aircraft).

Comment: You can request a seat and they will happily comply if you are early and that type is available. I almost always use this.